# Why don't HTML suggestions work in my Javascript file which has HTML elements in it?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, web-component

I am creating and HTML web component in JavaScript. However, when i start writing the HTML in it the suggestions and completions don't work. Below is the code:

```
class CardComponent extends LitElement {

    render() {
        return html`
        
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>11.12.2021</p>
            <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        </div>

        <style>
            .card {
                width:400px;
                bordr:2px solid red;
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>

        `
    }
}
```

I had to type the entire HTML manually myself except for the curly braces which close on their own. Also, the tags in this part were not color coded in the IDE.

How do I enable the suggestions and auto completion?

Comment: Have you checked: https://lit.dev/docs/tools/development/

Comment: Did I miss the part where you mention your IDE?